# TestExecutionListeners annotation prevents spring beans being wired in

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

Following the [cassandra-unit with spring example](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/wiki/Spring-for-Cassandra-unit) I found the spring beans are not wired into the testclass resulting in nullpointer exceptions. I tried to minimise the problem and found it is probably not the Cassandra part, but instead the presence of a `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation, together with a `AbstractTestExecutionListener` extended class.

```
org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.0.RELEASE (Also fails with 3.2.14.RELEASE).
org.springframework:spring-test:4.2.0.RELEASE
junit.junit:4.11

JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_40
MAC OS X 10.10.5
```

my TestClass looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ AppTestListener.class }) <-- OK when removed
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfiguration.class })

public class MyTest {
  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @Test
  public void testMyService() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(myService);
    Assert.assertEquals("didit", myService.doIt());
  }
}
```

AppTestListener:

```
public class AppTestListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {
  @Override
  public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("test");
  }
}
```

Nothing special in the configuration class (and it also fails for configuration xml):

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public MyService myService() {
    return new MyService(); 
  }
}
```

When I remove the @TestExecutionListeners annotation in MyTest the test finishes as expected, but leaving that annotation makes the unittest fail on the assertNotNull.
What is happening?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For starters, the cassandra-unit example is unfortunately not really a good example since it leads to issues just like you encountered.

> When I remove the @TestExecutionListeners annotation in MyTest the
>   test finishes as expected, but leaving that annotation makes the
>   unittest fail on the assertNotNull. What is happening?

When you declare `@TestExecutionListeners(AppTestListener.class)` on a test class that does not extend any other test class annotated with `@TestExecutionListeners` you are effectively telling Spring to load **only** your `AppTestListener`, when you actually want to use `AppTestListener` in combination with the default listeners from Spring (e.g., the `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener` which adds support for dependency injection of beans from the `ApplicationContext`).

For details, please read the entire [TestExecutionListener configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tel-config) section of the Spring reference manual.

Here's how to fix your problem.

**Before Spring Framework 4.1**

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({
  CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
  DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
  DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
  TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class
})
@CassandraUnit
public class MyCassandraUnitTest {

  @Test
  public void xxx_xxx() {
  }
}
```

**After Spring Framework 4.1**

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(
  listeners = CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
  mergeMode = MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS
)
@CassandraUnit
public class MyCassandraUnitTest {

  @Test
  public void xxx_xxx() {
  }
}
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

p.s. I created an [issue for Cassandra Unit](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/issues/137) so that they address this in their examples.